# How can I load the file.lua library globally by C++ without having to import it with : loadfile("file.lua")()?

Tags: c++, json, lua, luac

I have a library called " json.lua " found on this github : [github json.lua](https://github.com/rxi/json.lua)

I'm importing this library through the main.lua file like this:

```
local json = loadfile("json.lua")() -- json = library loaded
print("json decoded : "..json.decode("13E+2")) -- will print : json decoded = 1300.0
```

but I want to use the " **json** " variable globally, **without having to import it with : loadfile("json.lua")()**

is there any way to load *json.lua* **OR** *json.lua file string*  directly into the lua VM globally so that any other file ( main1.lua, main2.lua, main3.lua, ...lua ) I just type " json.ANY_FUNCTION " and go work?

Comment: Yes. But how depends on how you did the integration of the lua interpreter in your c++ code. There is nothing we can do for you without seeing that.

Comment: I used the simplest form of integration, just importing the lua library, initializing the VM with luaL_newstate(), after that loading lua's base libraries and after that running : luaL_dofile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in C++ before loading your scripts:

```
luaL_dostring(L,"json = dofile('json.lua')");
```

Comment: can you run the code inside "json.lua" instead of loading the file "json.lua"?

Comment: @waldemarlima, that's what `luaL_dostring` does.

Comment: alright, but how would I make the code inside json.lua, global?

Comment: LIKE = luaL_dostring(L, "json = {CODE_INSIDE_JSON.LUA} ");  , without having to call the file, json.lua, but loading the code inside...

Comment: @waldemarlima, oh, you want to put the whole script in your C++ program as a string? If so, see http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinToCee

Comment: isn't there a simpler way? xD